# hot water coming out of outside faucet

Tags: plumbing

A couple of things.   I have two bathrooms and one of them, you cant really take a shower due to not enough hot water.  You can shower for about 5-10 mins and the water is now warm, even when the handle is all the way on hot.    Also a outdoor faucet has cool, then hot, then cold water coming out of it.  I have checked the pipes and they are ran correctly, (hot-hot, cold to cold).   My bathroom has no problem due to the kind of shower I have.
This a new build and the water is not "hot" anywhere.  I have the temp. on the tanks 130.
Help
Carolyn Stump

Comment: Make sure all your shutoff valves are open and recheck the pipe runs. If you've got hot water coming out of an outdoor faucet, somethings wrong.  If it's a new build, get with the contractor to fix the problem.

Comment: @JACK sounds like a recirc pump...

Comment: Who did the work - a professional or a DIY?

Comment: Do you have forced-air heat? A cold water line running through a duct may allow a length of pipe to become warm (or hot) when there is no water flowing.

Comment: Since one of your showers apparently *can* run hot forever, this points to a problem with the hot-water lines going to the other bathroom.  Check for incorrect plumbing connections as well as local backflow preventers.  How many different hot-water tanks do you have?  If the bathrooms are on different tanks, then the location of the problem is easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

A few possible causes of the issue:

- There are long runs of **uninsulated** cold and hot water pipes next to each other. The hot water pipe should be insulated to keep the water inside *hot*, and the parallel pipe *cold*. If you have any way to access the supply lines, insulate at least the hot water pipe. It is also possible that insulation in a wall or crawlspace, as opposed to pipe wrap, has been damaged. For example, if water has leaked into a wall, perhaps from an ice dam, it can cause wall insulation, particularly *cellulose* insulation, to clump and settle, and rodents can remove pipe insulation in a crawlspace.
- Backflow from convection and from expansion of water in the hot water tank is pushing heated hot water *backwards*, into the cold water supply line, wasting that heat. Install a [backflow preventer](https://www.doityourself.com/stry/2-tips-to-installing-a-backflow-preventer-on-a-water-heater). A quick test for that issue is to partially throttle the water entering the heater, *but do not reduce it to a trickle*, let the tank overheat and be damaged! If water in the outside tap is now noticeably cooler, backflow is at least one culprit. *Reopen the heater valve after testing!~*